# If I use a pointer in a function to populate a list, do I have to delete that pointer at the end of the function in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

If I use a pointer in a function to populate a list, do I have to delete that pointer at the end of the function, or the list's destructor will do the work in c++?

For example:

```
void populateList() {
  Human* human;
  List<Human> myList;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    human = new Human();
    myList.push_back(*human);
  }
}
```

Should I delete the pointer at the end of the function, or it is not needed, because it is not a memory leak?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish of going through all this trouble, instead of simply `myList.push_back(Human{});`? And, yes, this is a memory leak. This is a very common memory leak, so common that it even has a name: "pointless use of pointers".

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all here?

Comment: As the code is written you have to delete it at the end of the **loop**. The rule is very simple, every time you `new` you must also `delete`. So since there is one new each time round the loop, there also needs to be one delete each time round the loop. But as others are saying there's no need to use new or pointers at all. What makes you think you must use a pointer? It seems to be a newbie disease, use pointers everywhere.

Comment: managing memory manually looks complicated at first, but actually it is rather simple. All you need to remember is: You need exactly 0 `delete`s for 0 `new`s. Anything else is a (potential) leak

Comment: Here's a hint, if you create a pointer (using `new` perhaps) only to immediately get rid of that pointer using `*` (the dereference operator) that's a clue that you didn't need to create the pointer in the first place.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I love it :) I'm stealing that quote ;)

Comment: @cigien inspired by Bjarne, somewhere he once wrote something along the line of "if you have a `new` you have a leak" (note, no mention of matching the `delete`). That made me think for a while, then I was impressed by his wisdom

Comment: @idclev463035818 Oh, very nice. If you happen to find that quote, can you share it with me?

Comment: @cigien when I find it, I will remember

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
myList.push_back(*human);
```

you are making a copy of the dynamically allocated object pointed at by the `human` pointer, so the `myList` destructor will only clean up that copy. You do need to manually free the dynamically allocated memory  pointed at by `human`, to avoid leaking that memory.

However, in this case there seems to be no reason to dynamically allocate memory with `new` at all. You could just create a local `Human` and add that to `myList`. Then there are no issues with memory leaks since there
is no dynamically allocation, and all the objects will be correctly cleaned up when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a pointer here as you could simply, do this:

```
void populateList() {
  List<Human> myList;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    Human human; //if the constructor of human creates the same thing every time, you could also put this line before the for loop
    myList.push_back(human);
  }
}
```

Declaring a variable in c++ also constructs it.

What you are doing is creating a pointer, than creating a new instance of `Human` and making the pointer point to that instance. Than basically copying it to the list, because you are only giving the list a copy. It couldn't delete your pointer even if you wanted to, so you should delete your human instance. If you do insist on using pointers you should do this:

```
void populateList() {
  Human* human;
  List<Human> myList;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    human = new Human();
    myList.push_back(*human);
    delete human;
  }
}
```